# Redirecting with a query string in Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, routes, query-string

At some point in the past, my company changed our search tool and with it the format of the search query in the url.

It used to be a typical query parameter:

```
/product-name-some-digits-12345?q=searchterm
```

But now it's sent as a fragment:

```
/product-name-some-digits-12345##search:query=searchterm
```

We have a small number of visits to pages in the old format - either links out there in the ether, or users searching before the JS which powers the search has loaded. To mitigate this, I'd like to write a route to redirect from the old format to the new.

I thought I could do this by adding something like the below to the route file `web.php`:

```php
Route::get('{base}?q={query}', function ($base, $query) {
    // output for now, write redirect later
    dd($base . '#search:query=' . $query);
})->where([
    'base' => '[^\?]?',
    'query' => '.*',
]);
```

But the route just isn't being hit.

**How can I write a Laravel route to act when a query string is present?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Laravel would translate that Route, but I'm also not surprised that the Route wouldn't be accessible. To debug your available routes, you can use this Artisan command:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Typically, you don't define Query String parameters directly in the Route like `?q={query}`, since you really don't have to; Query Strings are implicit; they can be present on any route, but aren't required.

If you change the route to a simple `Route::get('{base}')`, and add a check for `$request->has('q')`, you should be able to handle the redirect:

```php
Route::get('{base}', function ($base) {
  if (request()->has('q')) {
    return redirect()->url($base . '#search:query=' . request()->input('q'));
  }
  // ...
});
```

`request()` is available app-wide and can be used to check for Query String or Body/Post Parameters. The alternative is to use Injection, like:

```
Route::get('{base}', function (Request $request, $base){ ... });
```

Then use `$request->has()` and `$request->input()`, but they are syntactically the same.

Another approach would be to wrap your routes with a Middleware that checks the same thing. Syntax would be similar, in that you check for the presence of `?q=whatever` via `$request->has('q')`, and redirect or continue as required. Documentation for that can be found here:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware